# how to add dataframes where the column names are same

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame `df1` and `df2`. I want to create a new data frame `df3` which is simply the sum of`df1` and `df2` where the column names are same.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,4,5),x2=c(5,6,7),x3=c(9,9,10))
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,6,3),x2=c(4,3,1),x3=c(5,4,6),x4=c(7,6,7))

 df1
    x1  x2  x3
 1  1   5   9
 2  4   6   9
 3  5   7   10

df2
    x1  x2  x3  x4
 1  1   4   5   7
 2  6   3   4   6
 3  3   1   6   7

df3
    x1  x2  x3  x4
 1  2   9   14  7
 2  10  9   13  6
 3  8   8   16  7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We find the column names that are common in both 'df1' and 'df2' ('nm1').  Create a copy of 'df2' ('df3').  Add the subset of datasets (`df1[nm1]`, `df2[nm1]`) and assign it to the corresponding subset of 'df3'.

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df3 <- df2
df3[nm1] <- df1[nm1]+df2[nm1]
df3
#  x1 x2 x3 x4
#1  2  9 14  7
#2 10  9 13  6
#3  8  8 16  7
```

---

In case there are other unique columns in 'df1' that are not in 'df2' and viceversa, one option would be to place the datasets in a `list`, then `rbind` them with `rbindlist` (from `data.table`), create a sequence column ('N') and use `lapply` to get the `sum` of each of the columns.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE)[,
       N:= 1:.N, .id][,lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE) , 
           by = N , .SDcols=x1:x4][, N:= NULL][]
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
#1:  2  9 14  7
#2: 10  9 13  6
#3:  8  8 16  7
```

Comment: This would not preserve columns in `df1` not also present in `df2`, if such existed.

Comment: @RHertel Here, I assumed that the "df3" has the same dimension as "df2".  I am not sure whether the OP wants to have a new dataset with all the columns that are unique to df1, df2 and the common ones.

Comment: @akrun. would it make sense if I cbind `df1` and `df2` and then aggregate the identical columns?

Comment: @HaagenDaz  I used another approach which would be a bit more general if in any case you have unique columns in both datasets.

Comment: @akrun thanks, the second approach works better as it can be applied to all sceanrios

Comment: @akrun  can this be applied if you more than two data frames?

Comment: @HaagenDaz  Yes, you place them in a list and do as above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107454/discussion-between-haagendaz-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea:

```
cbind(
    df1[intersect(names(df1),names(df2))]+df2[intersect(names(df1),names(df2))],
    df1[setdiff(names(df1),names(df2))],
    df2[setdiff(names(df2),names(df1))]
);
##   x1 x2 x3 x4
## 1  2  9 14  7
## 2 10  9 13  6
## 3  8  8 16  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
i <- which((!names(df2) %in% names(df1)))
a <- df2[-i]+df1
df3 <- cbind(a, df2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,4,5),x2=c(5,6,7),x3=c(9,9,10))
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,6,3),x2=c(4,3,1),x3=c(5,4,6),x4=c(7,6,7))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all=T, sort=F)
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df4 <- df3[1:(nrow(df3)/2), ] + df3[(nrow(df3)/2+1):nrow(df3), ]
df4
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1  2  9 14  7
# 2 10  9 13  6
# 3  8  8 16  7
```